# Access specific Android system fonts via CSS

Tags: android, css, web-applications, fonts, webview

I'm building a webapp off of Android's WebView class. Currently, when I point it at my page, any Japanese characters are rendered with the DroidSansFallback font which is what I want. However, when the device's language is changed to Japanese, it begins rendering Japanese characters in the MTLmr3m.ttf font, which sometimes affects the layout of the webpage that is being loaded. After doing some research, I've found that this is due to this snippet of code out of the fallback_fonts.xml system file

```
<family>
    <fileset>
        <file lang="ja">MTLmr3m.ttf</file>
    </fileset>
</family>
```

Presumably I can't change this system file, but is there a way I can directly reference the DroidSansFallback.ttf file and set the font to that when the string has Japanese characters so that this fonts is used regardless of the language the device is set to?

I've tried using `shouldInterceptRequest()` from the WebViewClient class to catch a dummy protocol in a css @font-face delcaration like this: `src: url("font:Droid") format("truetype");` and send the font that way via this code:

```
...
if (url.equals("font:Droid")){  
    File font = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory(),"/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(font);
    String encoding="UTF-8";
    WebResourceResponse font = new WebResourceResponse("font/ttf",encoding,is);
    return font;
}
...
```

The method catches the request, but does not return the WebResourceResponse as expected.

I was hoping maybe there was a solution to this where I could reference the font I want in the CSS somehow. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I know this must be late to answer, but may be it's useful to someone.

**1)** you can not access android root directory "**/**" unless you have Root permission.
**2)** i believe you used the wrong mimetype for font, use this "**application/x-font-ttf**"

so you have 2 options, put your desired font in asset, or copy your font to external storage.
i will show the first way and leave the other to you.

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)
{
    if(url.contains("font/droid.ttf"))
    {
         return getFontFromAsset();
    }
}

private WebResourceResponse getFontFromAsset()
{       
    InputStream fontIn = null;
    try 
    {
        fontIn = yourContext.getAssets().open("DroidSansFallback.ttf");         
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(fontIn == null)
        return null;
    else
    {           
        WebResourceResponse response = new WebResourceResponse("application/x-font-ttf", "UTF-8", fontIn);
        return response;
    }       
}
```

also you might use some thing like this for your css:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'droid'; src: url('font/droid.ttf');} body { font-family: 'droid';}
```

this is the working method for me.